# need to change hard code and filter in this query

Tags: sql, db2-400

The db is db2-400 in the following I need to add this part
"`WHERE T01.OTTRNC IN ('001', 'CQU', 'RQU',`"

it should check against table '`Codes`' if ottrnc being read is in this table codes, rather than this hard coding. 
I also want to add this column - `t01.OTUSRN` if its located in this table '`CLOSERS`' then we want to filter the entire on this condition as well.

```
SELECT ALL T01.OTCOM#, T02.IHPTTC,                       
T02.IHSLR#, T01.OTTRT,                                                                 
T01.OTORD#, T02.IHINV#, T01.OTTRND, T02.IHORDT,               
T02.IHDOCD, T02.IHORG$, T02.IHORD$,                                            
T02.IHORG$-(T02.IHORD$) AS                
INVAMT, T01.OTUSRN, T01.OTTRNC                                                    
FROM ASTDTA.OETRANOT T01                           
     INNER JOIN                                                                                               
ASTDTA.OEINHDIH T02 ON T01.OTCOM# = T02.IHCOM#                                
AND     
T01.OTORD# = T02.IHORD#                                                                       
WHERE T01.OTTRNC IN ('001', 'CQU', 'RQU',                                                                                        
'CRF',                                                                       
'RRF', 'CWA', 'RWA', 'OCS', 'CRF', 'RBC', 'LMY', 'BCS',                                                                                                  
'BCQ')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both problems can be solved with sub queries, once using `IN` and once `NOT EXISTS`.

```
WHERE
   T01.OTTRNC IN (SELECT Code FROM Codes) AND
   NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Closers WHERE T01.OTUSRN = OTUSRN)
```